# JQUERY + Increment Member Counter

Tags: jquery, html

I'm building a member counter for a site that will look like this:

[image]

I will use JQUERY/AJAX/PHP/Mysql to bring the new membership number to the site every 30secs or so. This i can do.

The bit I'm struggling with is getting counter to increment. Basically I want it to count up by the new membership. If the increase was 3 members then it would display:

2,145,356
2,145,357
2,145,358

I would need a touch of a delay between number so it gives the feeling of incrementing.

I have put the code I'm working on here: http://jsfiddle.net/adamadam123/V3MCu/8/

```
<div id="siteCounterContainer">
  <button id="siteCounterMembers">Increment</button>
  <span id="siteCounterNumber">2,145,355</span>
</div>​


 $(function() {

$('button#siteCounterMembers').click(function() {
    var ranNumber = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 22);
    alert(ranNumber);

   var originalNumber = $('span#siteCounterNumber').text().replace(/\,/g, '');
   //alert(originalNumber);

   myInteger = parseInt(originalNumber);
   alert(myInteger);

   for(var i=0; i<ranNumber; i++) {
       var newNumber = myInteger + 1;
       alert(newNumber);

   } 
});
 });
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are adding everytime 1 + myInteger (myInteger is in every loop step the same), this works for me:

```
$('button#siteCounterMembers').click(function() {
   var originalNumber = $('span#siteCounterNumber').text().replace(/\,/g, '');
   var ranNumber = parseInt(1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 22), 10);
   var myInteger = parseInt(originalNumber, 10);
   for(var i=0; i<ranNumber; i++) {
       var newNumber = myInteger + (i+1)
       alert(newNumber);          
   }



});
```